# How to detect programmatically when a user enables a widget in Today View

Tags: ios, swift, widget, today-extension

I have an app with a widget, that the user can enable or disable in the iphone's Today View.
Is there a way to detect programmatically when a user enables an app extension (widget)?
I'd like to count users who install the widget, so i have to catch the exact moment when the user click "enable" in my app (it would be useful catch "disable" action too).
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you find any method to check if the user has disable/enable an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for asking the question.

When the user allows to widget to show in the notification center, then your widget life cycle method gets called.

Here you need to manage by flagging some as below
For example

If the widget launches the first time and upload count to the server successfully then your `NSUserDefault` is set to `YES` else Set it to `NO`

If your app is not launched the first time then do the regular process then no need to upload in the server

Comment: thanks for the reply,  in this way i can't catch the "disable" action right?  I've used a bool in NSUserDefault to count the FIRST time that the widget is created, but if the user disables the widget, if i can't catch it, i can't setting the boolean again..

Comment: If user disable then we don't have any command so it is not possible when widget in disable mode.